# Как удалить все пробелы в БД SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как удалить все пробелы в БД SQL?
На примере:

JS - `" Тест на ".replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');`

Jquery - `trim(" Тест на ");`

php - `str_replace(" ",""," Тест на ");`

Comment: Нужно удалить пробелы в ячейке таблицы в базе? Конкретизируй вопрос

Comment: @Doofy Могу ли я уточнить что Вы ( к незнакомому человеку, нужно обращатсья на 'Вы')  имеете  в виду?  А где еще могут быть пробелы кроме как в `string`? ` в ячейке таблицы в базе?` - в БД SQL (в названии имени дампа. Вы издеваетесь? Если бы я что-то нетривиальное имел в виду, я бы наверное написал об этом. Конечто же в ячейке, а в (ах) я уже сам.

Comment: Ох уж простите меня быдла некультурного, мсье) Попробуйте `$out = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);`

Comment: @Doofy Большое спасибо Вам). Но я уже ответ ниже оставил.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если нужно удалить все пробелы:

```
SELECT REPLACE( `field`, ' ', '' ) FROM `table`;
```

Если только первые/последние:

```
SELECT TRIM( `field` ) FROM `table`;
```

P.S. Читайте [доки](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/reference.html#string-functions), они - рулез (C).

Comment: Господи, Спасибо, Большое,  Вам. Но у вас не правильно. Мы удаляем при получении данных, а не изменяем их в БД, в втором варианте. А в первом вообще все пробелы ппц удалит.  Нужно по дгурому же. Ладно не трудитесь, спасибо.   ---- PS `P.S. Читайте доки, они - рулез (C).` только нужно их читать внимательно  ^& ^  UPDATE test_table SET text = LTRIM(RTRIM(text));

Comment: Что нужно по-другому? В постановке вопроса вообще разное делается в разных случаях.

Comment: Как??? `Как удалить все пробелы в БД SQL? 1.На примере` - Удалить не при получении данных, а в самой БД. Ниже я привел примеры как именно необходимо удалить пробелы. Всем известно что функция "trim" на всех языках программирования, наверное , удаляет пробелы с начала строки и с её конца. Следовательно, для четкого озознания сути вопроса, должно было быть более чем достаточно данных.Как мне казалось. Но всё равно спасибо. Хорошего вам настроения и здоровья!)

Comment: Пример на PHP удаляет именно все пробелы, а не только концевые.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы удалить пробелы справа и слева, можно сделать так:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = TRIM( `field` )
```

Что бы убрать только пробел слева:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = LTRIM( `field` )
```

Соответственно что бы убрать пробел справа:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = RTRIM( `field` )
```

Что бы вообще все пробелы убрать:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = STR_REPLACE(" ","", `field` ),
```

выполнить нужно несколько раз! что б все пробелы убрать, их может быть много.

---

PS
Наврал с последним запросом, правильный:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE( field, ' ', '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, ' ', '')
```

Comment: Обычно новый ответ должен чем-то отличаться от ранее данных. Чем отличается ваш от, например, [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757241/217579)?